# Most efficient way to stand?

Tags: legs, posture

A question out of curiosity. What's the best way to stand in one place for a long time, say an hour? "Best" in terms of energy consumption; but mainly ankles, knees and muscle fatigue. Stand evenly on both feet? Or shift most of your weight on one foot in turns? Is there some "optimal" foot alignment?

I'm asking both for answers from experience and a theoretical explanation what and why :)

*Update*: not required to stand still. If you want to be precise, assume you can use no more than a square meter of floor, as long as you're standing the whole time.

Answer (score 3):

Probably depends just how still you have to stand.  Beefeaters (the fellows in black hats and red jackets who stand at attention at the Tower of London) have to stand absolutely still for hours at a time.  They alternate weight between toe and heel, with the feet a half-phase off from each other (left toe & right heel, then left heel & right toe.)  Knees not locked.

Even so, [occasionally the blood pools and they pass out.](http://rarehistoricalphotos.com/guard-of-honor-passes-out-as-queen-elizabeth-ii-rides-past-during-the-trooping-the-color-parade-1970/)

[image: A beefeater passes out]

For versions of "stand still" that don't require quite so much "still", there are probably other techniques that are better.